# AUCTeX folding: don't display error

Tags: latex, auctex, beamer

Here is a common beamer slide:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item \textbf<1>{Item one}
  \item \textbf<2>{Item two}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

This is what it looks like in Emacs when folded using the AUCTeX `TeX-fold-mode`:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{itemize}
  * [Error: No content found]<1>{Item one}
  * [Error: No content found]<2>{Item two}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

There are other situations too where valid LaTeX is folded with errors, which are very annoying to look at.

Is there any way of telling AUCTeX to just not fold stuff that it can't fold, so I don't see these errors anymore? Or is there a better way of dealing with this?